TypeError: "cur.handler.call" is not a function
I added the RichTextEditor, everything works functionally...
but the "FileBrowser" is not working, and I am getting this error...
I'm using (version 26.2.5).
all things up to date, and I tried to reproduce it in a fresh app. and still getting this error

my code:
import * as React from 'react';
import './fileManager.scss'
import { FileManagerComponent, Inject, NavigationPane, DetailsView, Toolbar } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-filemanager';
import { API_URL } from "../../config";

/**
 * File Manager full functionalities sample
 */
const FileManager = () => {

    const hostUrl: string = API_URL;

    function beforeAjaxRequestSent(args: any) {
        args.ajaxSettings.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
            xhr.httpRequest.setRequestHeader('X-Access-Token', localStorage.getItem("auth"));
        }
    }

    const ajaxSettings =
    {
        url: hostUrl + "/fms",
        getImageUrl: hostUrl + "/fms/GetImage",
        uploadUrl: hostUrl + '/fms/Upload',
        downloadUrl: hostUrl + '/fms/Download'
    }
    const toolbarSettings = {
        items: ['NewFolder', 'Upload', 'SortBy', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'Delete', 'Refresh', 'Download', 'Rename', 'Selection', 'View', 'Details']
    }
    const contextMenuSettings = {
        layout: ['Upload', '|', 'SortBy', 'View', 'Refresh', '|', 'Paste', '|', 'NewFolder', '|', 'Details', '|', 'SelectAll']
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="control-section">
                <FileManagerComponent id="file-manager"
                    beforeSend={beforeAjaxRequestSent}
                    enableRtl={true}
                    ajaxSettings={ajaxSettings}
                    toolbarSettings={toolbarSettings}
                    contextMenuSettings={contextMenuSettings}
                    fileSelect={d => console.log('selected file',d)}
                    height='40rem'
                    view={"Details"}>
                    <Inject services={[NavigationPane, DetailsView, Toolbar]} />
                </FileManagerComponent>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default FileManager;


I see no cur reference in the code you shared. Please [edit] to include a complete and relevant [mcve].

Hi @Drew Reese, the problem is that "cur" is in the main package. I didn't define it!
